# How to handle error installing packge chemfp in Python

Tags: python

I have been trying to install the package `chemfp` to Pychram and receive the error :

**Command output:**

```
Collecting chemfp
  Downloading chemfp-1.6.1.tar.gz (560 kB)
Using legacy setup.py install for chemfp, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: chemfp
    Running setup.py install for chemfp: started
    Running setup.py install for chemfp: finished with status 'error'

    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pycharm-packaging\\chemfp\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pycharm-packaging\\chemfp\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-kdb4ekqq\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Include\chemfp'
         cwd: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\chemfp\
    Complete output (160 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\chemfp
    copying chemfp\arena.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\chemfp
    copying chemfp\argparse.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\chemfp
    copying chemfp\bitops.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\chemfp
    copying chemfp\encodings.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\chemfp
    copying chemfp\fps_io.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\chemfp
    copying chemfp\fps_search.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\chemfp
    copying chemfp\io.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\chemfp
    copying chemfp\openbabel.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\chemfp
    copying chemfp\openbabel_patterns.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\chemfp
    copying chemfp\openeye.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\chemfp
    copying chemfp\openeye_patterns.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\chemfp
    copying chemfp\pattern_fingerprinter.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\chemfp
    copying chemfp\rdkit.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\chemfp
    copying chemfp\rdkit_patterns.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\chemfp
    copying chemfp\sdf_reader.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\chemfp
    copying chemfp\search.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\chemfp
    copying chemfp\slow.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\chemfp
    copying chemfp\types.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\chemfp
    copying chemfp\_compat.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\chemfp
    copying chemfp\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\chemfp
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\chemfp\commandline
    copying chemfp\commandline\cmdsupport.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\chemfp\commandline
    copying chemfp\commandline\fpcat.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\chemfp\commandline
    copying chemfp\commandline\ob2fps.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\chemfp\commandline
    copying chemfp\commandline\oe2fps.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\chemfp\commandline
    copying chemfp\commandline\rdkit2fps.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\chemfp\commandline
    copying chemfp\commandline\sdf2fps.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\chemfp\commandline
    copying chemfp\commandline\simsearch.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\chemfp\commandline
    copying chemfp\commandline\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\chemfp\commandline
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\chemfp\futures
    copying chemfp\futures\process.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\chemfp\futures
    copying chemfp\futures\thread.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\chemfp\futures
    copying chemfp\futures\_base.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\chemfp\futures
    copying chemfp\futures\_compat.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\chemfp\futures
    copying chemfp\futures\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\chemfp\futures
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\chemfp\progressbar
    copying chemfp\progressbar\compat.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\chemfp\progressbar
    copying chemfp\progressbar\widgets.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\chemfp\progressbar
    copying chemfp\progressbar\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\chemfp\progressbar
    copying chemfp\rdmaccs.patterns -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\chemfp
    copying chemfp\rdmaccs2.patterns -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\chemfp
    copying chemfp\substruct.patterns -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\chemfp
    warning: build_py: byte-compiling is disabled, skipping.
    
    running build_ext
    building '_chemfp' extension
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\src
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\x86_amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\include -IC:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\winrt" /Tcsrc/bitops.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\src/bitops.obj /openmp /Ox /GL
    bitops.c
    c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pycharm-packaging\chemfp\src\chemfp.h(135): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'len'
    c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pycharm-packaging\chemfp\src\chemfp.h(135): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'len'
    c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pycharm-packaging\chemfp\src\chemfp.h(135): error C2059: syntax error: ';'
    c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pycharm-packaging\chemfp\src\chemfp.h(135): error C2059: syntax error: ','
    c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pycharm-packaging\chemfp\src\chemfp.h(135): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
    c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pycharm-packaging\chemfp\src\chemfp.h(138): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'len'
    c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pycharm-packaging\chemfp\src\chemfp.h(138): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'len'
    c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pycharm-packaging\chemfp\src\chemfp.h(138): error C2059: syntax error: ';'
    c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pycharm-packaging\chemfp\src\chemfp.h(138): error C2059: syntax error: ','
    c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pycharm-packaging\chemfp\src\chemfp.h(138): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
    c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pycharm-packaging\chemfp\src\chemfp.h(142): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'len'
    c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pycharm-packaging\chemfp\src\chemfp.h(142): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'len'
    c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pycharm-packaging\chemfp\src\chemfp.h(142): error C2059: syntax error: ';'
    c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pycharm-packaging\chemfp\src\chemfp.h(142): error C2059: syntax error: ','
    c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pycharm-packaging\chemfp\src\chemfp.h(142): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
    c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pycharm-packaging\chemfp\src\chemfp.h(146): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'len'
    c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pycharm-packaging\chemfp\src\chemfp.h(146): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'len'
    c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pycharm-packaging\chemfp\src\chemfp.h(146): error C2059: syntax error: ';'
    c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pycharm-packaging\chemfp\src\chemfp.h(146): error C2059: syntax error: ','
    c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pycharm-packaging\chemfp\src\chemfp.h(146): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
    c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pycharm-packaging\chemfp\src\chemfp.h(151): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'len'
    c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pycharm-packaging\chemfp\src\chemfp.h(151): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'len'
    c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pycharm-packaging\chemfp\src\chemfp.h(151): error C2059: syntax error: ';'
    c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pycharm-packaging\chemfp\src\chemfp.h(151): error C2059: syntax error: ','
    c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pycharm-packaging\chemfp\src\chemfp.h(152): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
    c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pycharm-packaging\chemfp\src\chemfp.h(156): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'len'
    c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pycharm-packaging\chemfp\src\chemfp.h(156): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'len'
    c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pycharm-packaging\chemfp\src\chemfp.h(156): error C2059: syntax error: ';'
    c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pycharm-packaging\chemfp\src\chemfp.h(156): error C2059: syntax error: ','
    c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pycharm-packaging\chemfp\src\chemfp.h(156): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
    c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pycharm-packaging\chemfp\src\chemfp.h(160): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'len'
    c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pycharm-packaging\chemfp\src\chemfp.h(160): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'len'
    c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pycharm-packaging\chemfp\src\chemfp.h(160): error C2059: syntax error: ';'
    c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pycharm-packaging\chemfp\src\chemfp.h(160): error C2059: syntax error: ','
    c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pycharm-packaging\chemfp\src\chemfp.h(160): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
    c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pycharm-packaging\chemfp\src\chemfp.h(163): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'len'
    c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pycharm-packaging\chemfp\src\chemfp.h(163): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'len'
    c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pycharm-packaging\chemfp\src\chemfp.h(163): error C2059: syntax error: ';'
    c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pycharm-packaging\chemfp\src\chemfp.h(163): error C2059: syntax error: ','
    c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pycharm-packaging\chemfp\src\chemfp.h(163): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
    c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pycharm-packaging\chemfp\src\chemfp.h(166): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'len'
    c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pycharm-packaging\chemfp\src\chemfp.h(166): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'len'
    c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pycharm-packaging\chemfp\src\chemfp.h(166): error C2059: syntax error: ';'
    c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pycharm-packaging\chemfp\src\chemfp.h(166): error C2059: syntax error: ','
    c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pycharm-packaging\chemfp\src\chemfp.h(166): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
    c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pycharm-packaging\chemfp\src\chemfp.h(169): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'len'
    c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pycharm-packaging\chemfp\src\chemfp.h(169): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'len'
    c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pycharm-packaging\chemfp\src\chemfp.h(169): error C2059: syntax error: ';'
    c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pycharm-packaging\chemfp\src\chemfp.h(169): error C2059: syntax error: ','
    c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pycharm-packaging\chemfp\src\chemfp.h(169): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
    c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pycharm-packaging\chemfp\src\chemfp.h(174): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'len'
    c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pycharm-packaging\chemfp\src\chemfp.h(174): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'len'
    c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pycharm-packaging\chemfp\src\chemfp.h(174): error C2059: syntax error: ';'
    c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pycharm-packaging\chemfp\src\chemfp.h(174): error C2059: syntax error: ','
    c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pycharm-packaging\chemfp\src\chemfp.h(174): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
    c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pycharm-packaging\chemfp\src\chemfp.h(177): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'len'
    c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pycharm-packaging\chemfp\src\chemfp.h(177): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'len'
    c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pycharm-packaging\chemfp\src\chemfp.h(177): error C2059: syntax error: ';'
    c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pycharm-packaging\chemfp\src\chemfp.h(177): error C2059: syntax error: ','
    c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pycharm-packaging\chemfp\src\chemfp.h(178): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
    c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pycharm-packaging\chemfp\src\chemfp.h(182): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'len'
    c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pycharm-packaging\chemfp\src\chemfp.h(182): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'len'
    c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pycharm-packaging\chemfp\src\chemfp.h(182): error C2059: syntax error: ';'
    c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pycharm-packaging\chemfp\src\chemfp.h(182): error C2059: syntax error: ','
    c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pycharm-packaging\chemfp\src\chemfp.h(183): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
    c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pycharm-packaging\chemfp\src\chemfp.h(187): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'len'
    c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pycharm-packaging\chemfp\src\chemfp.h(187): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'len'
    c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pycharm-packaging\chemfp\src\chemfp.h(187): error C2059: syntax error: ';'
    c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pycharm-packaging\chemfp\src\chemfp.h(187): error C2059: syntax error: ','
    c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pycharm-packaging\chemfp\src\chemfp.h(188): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
    c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pycharm-packaging\chemfp\src\chemfp.h(190): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'size'
    c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pycharm-packaging\chemfp\src\chemfp.h(190): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'size'
    c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pycharm-packaging\chemfp\src\chemfp.h(190): error C2059: syntax error: ';'
    c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pycharm-packaging\chemfp\src\chemfp.h(190): error C2059: syntax error: ','
    c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pycharm-packaging\chemfp\src\chemfp.h(191): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
    c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pycharm-packaging\chemfp\src\chemfp.h(193): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'len'
    c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pycharm-packaging\chemfp\src\chemfp.h(193): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'len'
    c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pycharm-packaging\chemfp\src\chemfp.h(193): error C2059: syntax error: ';'
    c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pycharm-packaging\chemfp\src\chemfp.h(193): error C2059: syntax error: ','
    c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pycharm-packaging\chemfp\src\chemfp.h(194): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
    c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pycharm-packaging\chemfp\src\chemfp.h(197): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'len'
    c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pycharm-packaging\chemfp\src\chemfp.h(197): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'len'
    c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pycharm-packaging\chemfp\src\chemfp.h(197): error C2059: syntax error: ';'
    c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pycharm-packaging\chemfp\src\chemfp.h(197): error C2059: syntax error: ','
    c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pycharm-packaging\chemfp\src\chemfp.h(198): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
    c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pycharm-packaging\chemfp\src\chemfp.h(202): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'len'
    c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pycharm-packaging\chemfp\src\chemfp.h(202): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'len'
    c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pycharm-packaging\chemfp\src\chemfp.h(202): error C2059: syntax error: ';'
    c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pycharm-packaging\chemfp\src\chemfp.h(202): error C2059: syntax error: ','
    c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pycharm-packaging\chemfp\src\chemfp.h(202): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
    c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pycharm-packaging\chemfp\src\chemfp.h(205): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'len'
    c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pycharm-packaging\chemfp\src\chemfp.h(205): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'len'
    c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pycharm-packaging\chemfp\src\chemfp.h(205): error C2059: syntax error: ';'
    c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pycharm-packaging\chemfp\src\chemfp.h(205): error C2059: syntax error: ','
    c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pycharm-packaging\chemfp\src\chemfp.h(205): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
    c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pycharm-packaging\chemfp\src\chemfp.h(208): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'len'
    c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pycharm-packaging\chemfp\src\chemfp.h(208): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'len'
    c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pycharm-packaging\chemfp\src\chemfp.h(208): error C2059: syntax error: ';'
    c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pycharm-packaging\chemfp\src\chemfp.h(208): error C2059: syntax error: ','
    c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pycharm-packaging\chemfp\src\chemfp.h(208): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
    c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pycharm-packaging\chemfp\src\chemfp.h(211): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'len'
    c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pycharm-packaging\chemfp\src\chemfp.h(211): fatal error C1003: error count exceeds 100; stopping compilation
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\x86_amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pycharm-packaging\\chemfp\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pycharm-packaging\\chemfp\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-kdb4ekqq\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Include\chemfp' Check the logs for full command output.
WARNING: You are using pip version 20.1.1; however, version 20.2.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

I'm not sure of what othrer information is needed.

Any hint idea will be appriciated

Comment: Try first upgrading pip then perhaps installing `wheel` to avoid legacy install

Comment: @h0r53 - I upgraded the pip, `Successfully installed pip-20.2.3`. The `wheel`, I do not see all when go to `file`->  `setting` -> `python interpeter` -> `+`  to add packge (using pycharm)

Comment: pip install -U wheel should help with updating the wheel package.

Comment: There is an unofficial Windows binary for Python 2.7 on Christoph Gohlke's site. But for Python 3 it looks like you will need the commerical version.

Answer (score 0):

Chemfp doesn't support Windows, and hasn't since about chemfp 1.1.

Furthermore, the chemfp 1.x series doesn't support Python 3, and you are compiling with Python 3.7.

There is a pre-packaged/binary version of chemfp for Python 3.x on Linux-based OSes, but it isn't on PyPI. The [installation instructions](https://chemfp.com/download/) for it say:

```
python -m pip install chemfp -i https://chemfp.com/packages/
```